# Unevaluated Which

Tags: dynamic, conditional

I have the following Code:

```
Dynamic[Which[infoquestion == "Yes", 
"Please select the calculator that fits your needs best from our \
page", infoquestion == "No", 
"Thanks for visiting us. Please contact our team at +41 77 777 77 \
77 if you want to set up the loan.", True, "Please choose Yes or No"]]
```

My problem is, that I need to show "Please choose Yes or No", before something is evaluated without pre-defining the variable infoquestion. Is that somehow possible? I tried with True, but this does not apply to unevaluated input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dynamic[Which[infoquestion === "Yes", "Please select the calculator that fits your needs best from our page",
  infoquestion === "No", "Thanks for visiting us. Please contact our team at +41 77 777 77 77 if you want to set up the loan.",
  True, "Please choose Yes or No"]]
```

`Which` remains unevaluated if it cannot determine the `True` or `False` value of its conditions. However, `===` (`SameQ`) is perfect for this, as it is guaranteed to evaluate to either `True` or `False` for any input based on structural equivalence. `==` notably does not make this guarantee as it would interfere with its usage in symbolic algebra.